# How do i search and extract commented lines from a file using perl?

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I am new to Perl programming. Need your help in searching and extracting only commented lines from a file.  Below is an example

```
{
    This is line 1
    /*This is line 2
    This is line 3
    This is line 4*/
    This is line 5
}
```

I just want to search and extract only commented lines from above file.

Comment: You can use the flip-flop operator: `..`: http://perlhacks.com/2014/01/dots-perl/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\/
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/yV8gO3/1)**

Code

```
my $str = 'you string';
if ( $str =~ /\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\// ) {
    print "Comment: $1";
}
```

As [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) pointed in his comment, you can use dot with `s` flag (single line) instead of `[\s\S]`, so you could change your regex to:

```
\/\*(.*?)\*\/
```

Comment: I think it's only in JavaScript that `[\s\S]` is necessary. Just a dot is fine, with the `/s` modifier on the pattern

Comment: @Borodin yes, thanks. I'm good a perl dev. I've updated the answer with your comments